# Dynamically fetch values using env variable from yaml file using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to get the values of tenants in below yaml file using yq. The intent is to dynamically fetch the value depending on env variable.

Let's assume there's an env variable `var="az-dev"`, then tenants of az-dev should be retrieved.

I have given some tries as mentioned below but no luck.

**YAML file**

```
tenantlist:
  az-dev:
    tenants:
      - myazdev
  az-stage:
    tenants:
      - myazstg1 myazstg2
  aw-dev:
    tenants:
      - myawdev1 myawdev2
  aw-stage:
    tenants:
      - myawstg1 myawstg2
```

**Tries:**

```
var="az-dev" yq e '.tenantlist | select(. == env(var))' file.txt 

var=az-dev; yq '.tenantlist |= strenv(var) has("az-dev")' file.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: `- myazstg1 myazstg2` is a single word or list of elements

Comment: What is the expected output for `"az-dev"`?

Comment: @Inian It is a list of elements. Better to have the output stored in an array.

Comment: Your current update, makes it look. like a single value split by a space. Format your YAML to make it look a YAML list of elements and do update the expected output for your input

Comment: Well I can but there's already lot of previous code using this file, hence can't be changed. It doesn't matter if it's a single value or list, I can do the manipulation of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can simply index the required key name by `[..]` and get the corresponding tenants list

```bash
var="az-dev"  yq '.tenantlist[strenv(var)].tenants[]' yaml
```

Or just [pick](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/pick#pick-keys-from-map) the keys of interest from the map (available [since v4.22.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.22.1))

```bash
var="az-dev"  yq '.tenantlist | pick([strenv(var)]) | .[].tenants[]' yaml
```

Note: Since [4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), yq's `eval/e` command is the default command and no longer needs to be specified.

Comment: I had read this earlier but I want to do this using native yq capabilities.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Is the above solution not sufficient?

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting error although version is 4.x. 
```$ var="az-dev"  yq '.tenantlist[strenv(var)].tenants[]' config_kub_env.yaml
Error: unknown command ".tenantlist[strenv(var)].tenants[]" for "yq"
Run 'yq --help' for usage.``` 

Version: ```$ yq -V
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.16.2
```

Comment: Could you upgrade the yq version? to latest? the current one is https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.28.1 The one you have is really old

Comment: Great, working fine now after updating to latest version. Thanks for the help.